# How to change the value of a managed variable?

Tags: variables, windbg, managed, editing

My boolean variable can be referenced using the syntax

```
MPrime.exe Spirit.MPrimeComServerManager._isComServerReady
```

I have tried using the syntax

```
?? MPrime.exe Spirit.MPrimeComServerManager._isComServerReady=1
```

and I am not sure how to use `e*` commands with managed code.

This is the output from `!DumpObj`:

```
00007fff81a6d6e8  4000198   169   System.Boolean  1   static   0 _isComServerReady
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's write this example program to see how Booleans work in .NET and how to change the value with WinDbg:

```
using System;

namespace ChangeValueOfBoolean
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var h = new BooleanHolder();
            h.BoolValue = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Debug now. Boolean member has the value {0}", h.BoolValue);
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("After debugging, boolean member has the value {0}", h.BoolValue);
            h.BoolValue = true;
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class BooleanHolder
    {
        public bool BoolValue { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Steps to debug:

1. Compile it in debug mode
2. run the application.
3. attach WinDbg
4. fix the symbols `.symfix;.reload`
5. load the .NET extension `.loadby sos clr`
6. find the relevant object `!dumpheap -short -type BooleanHolder`
7. dump the object `!do <address>`
8. dump the raw value in memory `dd <address>+<offset> L1`

   We'll see that `true == 1`
9. edit the raw value `ed <address>+<offset> 0`
10. continue the program `g`
11. See the output on the console
12. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

    It has switched to `false`

Complete walkthrough in WinDbg:

```
0:004> .symfix;.reload
Reloading current modules
..........................
0:004> .loadby sos clr
0:004> !dumpheap -short -type BooleanHolder
025330c8
0:004> !do 025330c8
Name:        ChangeValueOfBoolean.BooleanHolder
MethodTable: 00144d74
EEClass:     00141804
Size:        12(0xc) bytes
File:        E:\Projekte\SVN\HelloWorlds\ChangeValueOfBoolean\bin\Debug\ChangeValueOfBoolean.exe
Fields:
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
704bf3d8  4000001        4       System.Boolean  1 instance        1 <BoolValue>k__BackingField
0:004> dd 025330c8+4 L1
025330cc  00000001
0:004> ed 025330c8+4 0
0:004> g
```

[image]

Comment: nice walkthrough would it would be great if you could show how to modify with c++ / c#? expression like ?? foo::booleanxxx::bool; ed foo:boolean::xxx instead of ed @@masm(address) anyway upvoted

Comment: @blabb: Hmm, I never did it that way. Should it be possible? I'll try

Comment: cdb -g booldoll.exe
1 <-----
(a4.bac): Control-C exception - code 40010005 (first chance)
0:001> ?? booldoll!foo
bool true
0:001> ed booldoll!foo 0
0:001> ?? booldoll!foo
bool false
0:001> g
0 <--------------
type booldoll.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
bool foo =true;
int main (void) {
  char temp[10];
  printf("%x\n",foo);
  gets_s(temp,sizeof(temp));
  printf("%x\n",foo);
  gets_s(temp,sizeof(temp));
}

Comment: @blabb: the question was tagged "managed". Your example looks like plain C++. I could not get the ?? operator to work with a pure C# program. Maybe it works in C++/CLI...

Comment: yep it is plain c++  i don't do c# much so i was wondering if you could do it that is all